# unexpected end syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

The following code:

```
require 'csv'

desc "Import Voters from CSV File"
task :import => [:environment] do

  file ="db/GOTV.csv"

  CSV.foreach(file, :headers => true) do |row|
    Voter.create({
      :last_name => row[0], 
      :first_name => row[1],
      :middle_name => row[2],
      :name_suffix => row[3],
      :primary_address => row[4],
      :primary_city => row[5],
      :primary_state => row[6],
      :primary_zip => row[7],
      :primary_zip4 => row[8],
      :primary_unit => row[9],
      :primary_unit_number => row[10],
      :phone_number => row[11],
      :phone_code => row[12],
      :gender => row[13],
      :party_code => row[14],
      :voter_score => row[15],
      :congressional_district => row[16],
      :house_district => row[17],
      :senate_district => row[18],
      :county_name => row[19],
      :voter_key => row[20],
      :household_id => row[21],
      :client_id => row[22],
      :state_voter_id => row[23]
    })
  end
```

...is throwing the following error:

```
/Users/ecumbee/Desktop/cloudvoters/lib/tasks/import.rake:35: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting kEND
  end
     ^
```

I've tried removing the end, which throws the same error I've tried adding another end but it results in a can not compile error.

Edit:
error when adding a second end statement

```
Don't know how to build task 'db:import'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the error message, `$end` refers to the end of the input file, while `kEND` refers to the `end` keyword, so it's complaining about a missing `end`, not an extra one.

If you still get a syntax error after adding another `end`, that's something unrelated to this error.

Answer (score 2):

The `end` in your code is for the `CSV.foreach ... do` block. You're missing another `end` for the `task ... to` block.

If that still gives you a syntax error, edit your question and post that error instead.

Answer (score 1):

I know you said you tried to add another end and it didn't help, but the problem with your file is that it's missing the `end` keyword that will end the task

`task :import => [:environment] do`

Then can you give more information about the error you're getting once you add the missing `end` ?